# Query an OpenTTD server

Tags: java, udp, packet

I am using the following java code to try to send a [PACKET_UDP_CLIENT_FIND_SERVER](http://wiki.openttd.org/OpenTTDDevBlackBook/Network/UDP#Packet_List) ([source](http://svn.openttd.org/trunk/src/network/core/udp.h)) packet to query an OpenTTD server:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("publicserver-new.openttdcoop.org");
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
byte[] buf = new byte[]{0}; // 0 is number for CLIENT_FIND_SERVER, no extra data is needed (?)
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 3983);
socket.send(packet);

packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
packet.getData(); //
socket.close();
```

However, when I run the program the server never returns any packets. I have very little experience working with packets, and have been trying to figure out what to do by looking at [PHP and Python source code](https://dev.openttdcoop.org/projects/openttdlib/repository) that does the same thing. Hopefully someone will be able to help.
Thanks

EDIT:
I realized that the packet should actually contain the data `03 00 00`, the first two bytes contain the length, but I still haven't been able to get a response using a Packet Sender. Maybe I am listening on the wrong port?

Comment: On a side note because I'm interested, by OpenTTD do you mean Open Transport Tycoon Deluxe the game?

Comment: @ArunRamakrishnan Yes: http://www.openttd.org , the official name is OpenTTD for copyright reasons

Comment: Oh great! I had the original, aaaaaaaages ago. I heard about OpenTTD but never tried it. Thanks for the link, I think I shall try it now. Sorry for sidetracking your question though :)

Comment: I tried out the code, there is really no response coming back from the server. I've even tried by first starting the listening for response first in a separate thread. Maybe the API call is wrong? I'm not familiar with the OpenTTD api's however

Comment: @ArunRamakrishnan According to https://dev.openttdcoop.org/projects/openttdlib/repository/entry/includes/OpenTTDLibPacket.php#L37 , all the packet needs is a unit8 of 0. However, I haven't actually been able to get the PHP code to work, and I have little experience working with PHP

Comment: Yeah I've no experience with PHP either. I think the best step would be to somehow try and manually post the data and see if we get a response. I'll Google a bit and see if I can find a way to do that. I'm sure there would be browser plugins to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I had been doing wrong. This line:
`byte[] buf = new byte[]{0};`

should be:
`byte[] buf = new byte[]{0x03, 0x00, 0x00}` (hex for clarity)

The problem was that the first two bytes store the length of the data
The third byte is the actual request

In addition, the DatagamPacket needs to be reset to allow more than 3 bytes to be read

Comment: Ah that's it, that seemed to work. Thanks again for introducing me to OpenTTD, just started playing. Good memories of the original.